# How are certain Indian small businesses dealing with taxes?

Tags: taxes, india, small-business

When I am attempting to register a domain from a domain reseller, I don't see any tax component getting added by the reseller. However, Godaddy or HostGator adds 18% GST on top of the actual price of the domain. Therefore, the reseller could sell the domain at a much cheaper price than the name brand providers. I am just wondering if the reseller is legit. In other words, is the reseller somehow evading tax to attract more customers? Please find a screenshot of the final cart below.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't about personal finance.

Comment: Some companies are registered outside India and need not pay Indian taxes or the tax could be included in the price and not shown